# how to get the data from ajax request then use it in php conditional statemtn

Tags: php, ajax

I want to create an ajax post request that gets the value of the radio button then use it in a PHP conditional statement.

So far i have tried this code (all code is from one php file):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.radio-buttons input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var subject= $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'home.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'subject': subject
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response); 
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" class="radio-buttons ">
     <input class="radio-filter"  type="radio" name="subject" value="A">A</input> 
     <input class="radio-filter"  type="radio" name="subject" value="B">B</input>            
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {
    echo "Showing!";
}
```

the alert message shows the value of the radio button when I clicked them but the echo in PHP condition is not showing.

Comment: You need to alert the correct variable. `subject` is the variable you send to PHP. If you want to see the response, then change `alert(subject);` to `alert(response);`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,  interesting to note that your comment gives rise to 3 nearly identical answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `alert(subject);` which will just alert the value of the radio button as you've mentioned.

Change that line to `alert(response);` to alert the response on success.

Answer (score 2):

The `alert(subject)` needs to be `alert(response)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `alert(subject)` to `alert(response)`
because 'subject' is what you have been sent! so after it 'subject' will receipt by your PHP process and returned as response`(echo "Showing"`) on value of the function an object `success: function(response)`
and alert the response to see data/text "Showing"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.radio-buttons input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var subject= $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'home.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'subject': subject
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response); 
        }               
    });
});
```

});